# Change IconButton color

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, material-ui, icons

I want to add a custom color to IconButton

```
      <IconButton variant='contained'>
        <StarBorderRoundedIcon color='red' />
      </IconButton>
```

and this is the output

[image]

The red color is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Color property](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#color) on the icon here refers to the theme color property so you can define colors as `primary,success,action..`You can use style property instead something like

```
<IconButton variant='contained'>
        <StarBorderRoundedIcon style={{color:'red'}} />
</IconButton>
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-btxb95?file=demo.tsx)

or you can use sx property

```
<IconButton variant='contained'>
            <StarBorderRoundedIcon sx={{color:'red'}} />
    </IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<IconButton variant='contained' style="background-color: red">
  <StarBorderRoundedIcon/>
</IconButton>
```